# Python3 Run function while there is internet connection + check connection every x min

Tags: python-3.x, function

I currently have a function that checks if there is an internet connection and another one that checks a list of sites while there is an internet connection. My current code is an overkill because it is constantly connecting to Google to see if there is an internet connection. I am trying to change it so that it only checks for an internet connection every 15min while the check_site_function continues to run. If there is no internet then I would like the check_site_function to pause for 10min. I have no idea how to structure this and what to use to make it work this way.

**Current code**

```
def internet(host="8.8.8.8", port=53, timeout=3):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
        socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((host, port))
        return True
    except socket.error:
        print("disconnected")
        time.sleep(600)
        return internet()

while internet() is True and remaining_list != 0:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(check_sites_function, dict_list)
```

**What I'm trying to achieve**

```
#with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        #executor.map(check_sites_function, dict_list)

#check internet() every 15min
#if true do nothing
#if no internet then pause for 10min

#if internet after 10min continue executor.map
#if no internet pause for 10min
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, your function `check_site_function` will pause for 10 min if there is no internet connection, so then why do you want to check for internet connection every 15 mins?.

```
import socket
import time


def is_internet_available():
    ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    if ip_address == "127.0.0.1":
        return False
    return True


def check_site_function():
    while True:
        if is_internet_available():
            # do your stuff
        else:
            time.sleep(600)  # sleep for 10 mins
```

You can run this function on a separate thread or a process

As a thread,

```
t = Thread(target=check_site_function)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

As a process,

```
p = Process(target=check_site_function)
p.start()
```

Comment: Good point about the minutes and thanks for the answer but doesn't your solution also constantly check for an internet connection rather than checking every 15min?

Comment: The `check_site_function` needs a proper internet connection to work right?. Hence I am checking it frequently. Also, `is_internet_available` is not a costly one

Comment: If the IP is set to "127.0.0.1" then it will always be true because I'm still connected to the network with an IP right? I tested it by disconnected my internet.